# hsqldb 2.3.2 jdbc driver does not support ResultSet.first()?

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I am playing with HSQLDB+JDBC driver using JDK 8.
Using rs.next() looping results works fine, however, using rs.first() does not work: feature is not supported ?! Is is by design or a bug?

I plan to access hsqldb using Spring jdbc template, and I am concerned that I may stuck if I encounter such issue later on.

```
    String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9999/configdb";
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "SA", "");
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
                                "SELECT * FROM contacts");
        ) {

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        // rs.first() does not work !
        while(rs.next()){
            //do sth here
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("test jdbc connection failed", e);
    }
```

Comment: What do u mean by "rs.first() does not work"?R u getting any compilation/run-time error?

Comment: I got sql exception saying feature is not supported at runtime.

Comment: @Reimeus Default result sets are forward only, and the JDBC specification says that forward only should not support `first()` and other scrolling methods. Not sure what it has to do with being a "toy database"; it is about following the spec.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Totally agree!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make your ResultSet scrollable:

```
 PreparedStatement stmt= conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM contacts",
   ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
```

I think that should probably work